# How to start programming CFML with Railo

Tags: web-applications, railo, cfml

I believe I am missing something big and obvious here. I have decided to start learning CFML. I installed the open source [Railo Server](http://getrailo.org) and am saving to the correct path to run the cfm files from. When I run a file, it shows the HTML but not the CFML e.g.

I get this output

```
#variable1#
```

from this simple hello world code in notepad++:

```
<html>
<head><title>Hello World</title></head>
<body>
<cfset variable1 = "hello world">
<cfoutput>#variable1#</cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
```

I am treating the running of cfm files as I would PHP files. I believed it was the same idea. I can't find any tutorials that use Railo and notepad (perhaps because I have misunderstood the whole thing?). Most tutorials I have seen use adobe or dreamweaver, neither of which I have access to.

Cheers

Comment: Does the source of the web page show the coldfusion tags?

Comment: Editor doesn't matter. You need to be more explicit with _"I installed the open source Railo Server and am saving to the correct path to run the cfm files from."_ - which version did you install (Tomcat Installer or Express or other), to what location, and where are you putting the file?

Comment: Also, for more general help, the Railo community mailing list may be a better place to ask: http://groups.google.com/group/railo

Comment: Oh and also it is not "ColdFusion" you are using, it is **CFML**. ColdFusion is Adobe's proprietary server software. CFML is the programming language which ColdFusion and Railo share.

Comment: I get this source file:///C:/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/hello.cfml I used tomcat as you can see.

Comment: Well it's not recommended to use the ROOT context - check what `Host` entries are specified in `C:/railo/tomcat/conf/server.xml` ? Should be another webroot I think - but that's a separate issue. Might be `.cfml` extension isn't setup - that will be in `C:/railo/tomcat/conf/web.xml`, or just use `hello.cfm` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way to get up and running is following these steps:

**1)** Goto the [download page](http://www.getrailo.org/index.cfm/download/) and get the "Express with JRE edition" for your OS.

e.g. For Windows, select [railo-express-4.0.2.002-jre-win32.zip](http://www.getrailo.org/down.cfm?item=/railo/remote/download/4.0.2.002/railix/windows/railo-express-4.0.2.002-jre-win32.zip&thankyou=false)

**2)** Unzip the archive to a suitable location.

**3)** Execute the `start.bat` file (i.e. double-click it) to launch the Jetty servlet engine which Railo runs within.

**4)** Open a browser and go to `http://localhost:8888/` - you should get a "Welcome to Railo" screen.

**5)** In your Railo directory, go into webapps, then into railo, and you'll see the index.cfm which powers the above message. Rename it to something else, e.g. orig.index.cfm and go ahead and place the code above in a new index.cfm

**6)** Refresh the browser and you will see the "hello world" output you expect.

You can of course replace steps 1..3 with getting the Tomcat Installer and using that - it's a perfectly valid option, just takes more time to setup, whilst also being more convenient if connecting to an external web server.
(Both [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/) and [Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty/) are fully capable servlet engines able to power whatever you throw at them; neither require a distinct web server, but there are instances when adding one is beneficial.)

Comment: I did not start any servlet engine before. Also, my source was not from localhost, which feels like a really silly thing to do. I uninstalled and went through the steps as you stated and everything works. cheers

Comment: [(psst)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168399/how-can-tag-synonyms-be-remapped-or-unmapped)

Comment: I want just point out that you can also try commandbox: http://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox install it and then simply type server start. You will have a railo server showing up.

Answer (score 1):

In case you run into tutorials that are tailored to Adobe style and things don't behave as expected, don't forget to check out Kai Koenig's recent blog entries on notable differences between both server engines:

http://bloginblack.de/2013/02/cfml-differences-between-railo-and-coldfusion-9-10-part-1/

http://bloginblack.de/2013/02/cfml-differences-between-railo-and-coldfusion-910-part-2/